# Append 0 to missing observations in a dataframe.

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataset where I expect a fixed number of observations in a data-frame

```
A 20
B 10
C 5
```

However, upon running my analysis this is not always the case sometimes I find missing observations and the resulting dataframe looks like this

```
A 10
C 5
```

In this case there are no observations for B. I would want to append 0 observations to the final dataframe before ploting so as to indicate the values of the missing  observation.

final data frame should look like this

```
A 10
B 0
C 5
```

How can I accomplish this in R?

Comment: How do you create this dataset? Is this a data.frame with (only) two columns?

Comment: Is the first column is always upper case English letters? In other words, how do you know which levels are missing?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the **actual** code you're using, as we may be able to point out where you could add a line like `if(is.na(the_answer_for_B)) final_dataframe$B <- 0 `

Comment: @roman i have an external process that creates this dataset. The order of observations in the first column may vary i.e. it may not always be A B C but could be B C A.

Comment: Consider improving your question by incorporating all the information from your comments into the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the ID column (with A,B,C) as `factor` which seems appropriate here, you could plot the data and even those factor levels which are not in the data (but in the defined factor levels) will be plotted. Here's a small example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = LETTERS[1:3], x = rnorm(3))
df
#  ID        x
#1  A 1.350458
#2  B 1.340855
#3  C 1.311329
subdf <- df[c(1,3),]
subdf
#  ID        x
#1  A 1.350458
#3  C 1.311329
with(subdf, plot(x ~ ID))
```

You'll find that "B" is also present in the plot although it's not in the subsetted data.

Comment: This works in the manner you presented. But assuming the original data.frame has no information about redundant factor levels. This is why I was asking for the way the information is generated. Perhaps it could be solved at the source (using your logic).

Comment: True, @RomanLuštrik. Perhaps the question is not very precise whether the original data frame has information about factor levels. I interpreted "I expect a fixed number of observations" as that the factor levels are known, but maybe it's not the case. OP should clarify that.

Comment: The data is generated by an external program and I am using R to read it.  The original data therefore does not have information about the redundant factor levels as @Roman has stated.

Comment: @eastafri, in that case, my answer will not work. But you haven't answered the question how you know what levels are missing (or not) as in David's comment.

Comment: I know because I expect A B and C in all cases. In case there is no B, the external process, does not include it. For the purpose of plotting, I want to show that there was no B and therefore I want to 'inject' B into the data-frame and assign it a value of 0 in the second column. I think it may include scanning the first column and if I detect that B is missing, then append a new observation B with a value of 0. I should do this for all cases of missing observations. just dont know how to approach this efficiently in R

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something with `melt` and `dcast` from "reshape2".

Here's what I had in mind:

```
library(reshape2)
out <- dcast(
  melt(                           # Makes a data.frame from a list
    mget(ls(pattern = "df\\d")),  # Collects the relevant df in a list
    id.vars = "V1"),              # The variable to melt by
  L1 ~ V1, value.var = "value", fill = 0)  # Other options for dcast
out
#    L1  A  B C
# 1 df1 20 10 5
# 2 df2 10  0 5
```

From there, you could go back to a long data form.

```
melt(out, id.vars = "L1")
#    L1 variable value
# 1 df1        A    20
# 2 df2        A    10
# 3 df1        B    10
# 4 df2        B     0
# 5 df1        C     5
# 6 df2        C     5
```

If separate `data.frame`s are required, then you can also look at using `split`, but if you are just going to be plotting, this format should work just fine.

---

#### Sample data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "B", "C"), V2 = c(20L, 10L, 5L)), 
                 .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "C"), V2 = c(10L, 5L)), 
                 .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", 
                 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```